# Is there any website that shows which opening a certain player struggles against?

Tags: opening, statistics, websites

I just thought that it would be an interesting statistic to know which openings players like Carlsen and Fischer lost most against. Are there any websites that give these statistics?

Comment: I think chessgames.com has what you are looking for, for example: https://www.chessgames.com/perl/explorer?pid=52948&side=white, but you have to be a paid member to be able to see the full tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Opening tree](https://www.openingtree.com/) happens to be the website you are looking for. Using this, you can use a database of games or someone's Lichess or chess.com username to get detail about their games. It shows frequency, last played, best win, worst loss, win-loss stats and performance. It also have have fatabases of famous players in it. Checking Anand's games as black, after playing `1.e4 2.c5 3.Nf3` his worst performance is in Sicilian Defense: French Variation (elo performance 2644) with score 107/173 and worst loss was [Ljubojevic - Anand 1998](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1018861).

Overall, it's a nice free website.

Answer (score 0):

lichess.org has also this kind of tool for open profiles. I guess this tool is used or can be used for external chess websites. Probably, someone can find the open-source code of chess-insights tool in lichess-github repo. Read more about chess-insights [here](https://lichess.org/blog/VmZbaigAABACtXQC/chess-insights)